Approximating a discrete game by a continuum
Update I realize that this question might be very hard to answer precisely, so I would appreciate any reference (book or paper) that used the approximation of a discrete game by a continuous one.
Original
In the context of game theory, $n$ players may have a set of discrete actions, $A$, to choose from, how large should the set $A$ be in order to approximate the game as a continuum?
To make matters clear consider this  modification of the card game 'Blackjack' for two players.
Players A and B draw balls with replacement from an urn containing
$m$ balls marked $1,2, ... , m$. The aim of the play is to acquire a ball sum
as close to $m$ as possible, without exceeding this number.
First, player A draws a ball and obtains, say, ball $i$. They may then act
in two ways:
Decision 1. A is satisfied with $i$.
Decision 2. A draws another ball $j$ and so obtains a ball sum $i + j$.
Denote the total number attained by A after one of these decisions
by $s$. If $s > m$, player A loses the game; if $s \leq m$ the game continues as
follows:
Player B, who is informed about the value s, draws a ball and obtains,
say, ball $k$. There are two alternatives:

$s < k \leq m$. A loses the game.
$k \leq s$. Player B draws another ball and obtains, say, ball $l$. If $k+l\leq s$
or $k + l > m$, player A wins the game; otherwise B wins. (Here we
have used the rule that, in the case of a tie, A wins the game.)

So the question is For what values of $m$, if any, can one solve this game as if the players were sampling numbers uniformly at random form the interval $[0,m]$? Note I'm not looking for the solution of the problem above. It is just for illustration purposes. An ideal response could show that for large enough sets of actions, the continuum assumption is a good approximation to the Nash equilibrium in the discrete case. Listing references is even more appreciated.

What kind of answer do you expect? 721?

@MichaelGreinecker For starters, existence, i.e. a proof that a continuum approximation is close to the Nash solution for the discrete case!
